# Passing a variable to an advanced custom field in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Hoping someone can help me. I have some fields in Advanced Custom fields that are all related to colour swatches. What I want to do is populate these fields based on the swatch.

So I have the fields:

```
<?php the_field('image_one_black'); ?>
<?php the_field('image_two_black'); ?>
<?php the_field('image_three_black'); ?>
```

Where in each swatch the colour is consistent with the end of the field name.

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
<?php the_field('image_one_$swatch'); ?>
```

but can't work it out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a try like this
    <?php the_field('image_one_'.$swatch); ?>

Comment: You are a star! Thanks so much!

Comment: @chaitanya worth adding that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you use double quotes in your example above, this will unfold the variable, as double quoted strings can contain variables like this.

`the_field("image_one_$swatch")`

else @chaitanya's suggestion is probably the best:

`the_field('image_one_' . $swatch);`